# How to hide the help button from the dashboard of wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am new in wordpress and i want to hide the help button that is located on the top right of the dashboard in admin backend of wordpress. I don't want to use any plugin or remove its code. I just want to include css `display:none` to the `css` file but i am unable to locate exactly in which `.css` file i have to add this code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to enqueue your own admin css file.

Comment: How? I have not done that before.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts#Example:_Load_CSS_File_on_All_Admin_Pages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
 add_filter( 'contextual_help', 'mycontext_remove_help', 999, 3 );
      function mycontext_remove_help($old_help, $screen_id, $screen){
        $screen->remove_help_tabs();
        return $old_help;
    }
```